# Python Requests [403] Forbidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to execute a request GET with this URL: https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1394177/Preview/Spain-LaLiga-2019-2020-Barcelona-Villarreal

When I use Postman everything works perfectly but once I try with the python library Request, I get a 403 - Forbidden with this message:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" id="main-iframe" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=22&amp;xinfo=9-128015709-0%200NNN%20RT%281569365075496%2067%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B15%284%2c200%2c0%29%20U18&amp;incident_id=549001620109377666-353438150223530537&amp;edet=15&amp;cinfo=04000000" width="100%">
  Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 549001620109377666-353438150223530537
</iframe>
```

Here is my python code:

```py
url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1394177/Preview/Spain-LaLiga-2019-2020-Barcelona-Villarreal'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) ' 
                  'AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Here is a screenshot of the Postman request: https://ibb.co/PxkjkfS

If you have any idea why I have this issue with Requests and not with Postan, or if you have an alternative, let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Edit the question to include the definition of `url`.

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you showed the Postman request, so we have something to compare to.

Comment: I get a 200 response code when I run this with your supplied url and headers.

Comment: @RobertKearns can you tell me what is your requests version?